# What determines the "top answers" on stackexchange.com/users/?

Tags: support

From http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/558103#558103

- SE: https://stackexchange.com/users/9a3f8895-aeb3-4c3a-b694-fa303d4885c5?tab=top
- Unix: https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4565/gms8994

There are 2 10-v questions on Unix.SE that do not feature in the `stackexchange.com/users`

Would like to know answer to the question title

Comment: Yeah, I'm only seeing posts from Meta on my SE user page.

Comment: If I had a guess, it would be that you need at least 5 posts in the relevant site to count towards that. For example, exactly 5 posts are shown for Stack Overflow there. But on U/L, the user has only 1 question and 3 answers. That said, @mmyers provides a counter to my guess... and apparently myself, as I have 4 questions on Gaming but one is listed at the bottom of my top questions.

Comment: @Grace for another counter, I only have two answers in Superuser but one shows up in my top answers

Comment: My profile seems to work fine now, but the linked one still does not. Most curious. @Gra